# Scheduler CRON job for every 4 hours not working in Java SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, cron, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 */4 * * *")
@SchedulerLock(name = "InsightPhotoUploaderCronJob", lockAtMostFor = PT5M, lockAtLeastFor = PT5M)
```

Using above code to run a job every 4 hours. But after deployment of code it just ran once at 8:00 PM. Not sure what I am doing wrong here. Any feedback will be appreciated.

Please provide answers using 6 fields of cron expression. Thank you!

I have earlier tried

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 */10 * * * *")
@SchedulerLock(name = "InsightPhotoUploaderCronJob", lockAtMostFor = PT5M, lockAtLeastFor = PT5M)
```

To test if it runs every 10 minutes. It was working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I would say:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0/4 * * *")
```